# ElasticSearch get all terms from a field in all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get all terms with their frequencies for a specific field in all documents?
I found a solution how to get this information for a specified document with a termvector, but how do I do it for all documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lucene 4.0, you can access the terms for a field using [MultiFields](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiFields.html)

```
    IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(index);
    Terms terms = MultiFields.getFields(indexReader).terms("field");
    if(terms != null){
       TermsEnum iterator = terms.iterator();
       BytesRef byteRef = null;
       while((byteRef = iterator.next()) != null) {
         String term =  byteRef.utf8ToString();
         ...
       }
    }
```